# Lambda function in sorting function

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
lista = [3,4,5,2,1,6,8,3]
print lista # [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 3]
lista.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(y,x)) # sort descending
print lista # [8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1] -- it is sorted

lista = [3,4,5,2,1,6,8,3]
print lista # [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 3]
lista.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: y > x) # sort descending
print lista # [3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 8, 3] -- nothing happens
```

Why does the lambda function in the second block not sort the numbers?

Comment: I know that, but it is not the case in above example

Comment: Don't use the cmp argument. Use key.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The second example doesn't work because the function you're giving it isn't a valid comparator.

A valid comparator [is supposed to](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

> return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the
>   first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than
>   the second argument.

The function `lambda x,y: y > x` doesn't fulfil this contract.

Answer (score 8):

A `cmp` function needs to return a negative or positive number to indicate which element should go first (unless they are equal, then return 0).  Your `cmp` function of `y > x` will only return `0` or `1`.  Try changing it to the following:

```
lista.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: (y > x) - (y < x))
```

I took this from the [Python 3 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> If you really need the `cmp()` functionality, you could use the expression `(a > b) - (a < b)` as the equivalent for `cmp(a, b)`.

Answer (score 2):

x < y returns True or False, while cmp returns 1 and -1. This code works:

```
lista.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: 1 if x<y else -1)
```

Comment: actually, your "<" should be a ">"